# How do I get a list of checked out items with the Core Service?

Tags: core-service

I would like to get a list of all checked-out items in the system with the Core Service.  I have a feeling I need to use:

```
 GetSystemWideList(filter)
```

But, I can't find a filter to give me the list.  What filter would I need?

**Update:**
Here is the complete working solution

```
// get all checked out items from core service
string binding = "netTcp_2011";
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding);

RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData filter = new RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData();
XElement checkedOutItems = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
```

Comment: I don't get it...  The code indeed does return all the checked out items. But I don't get the relation between the filter object name (`RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData`) and the behavior that it returns all the checked out items. And  when the flag `LockFilter = LockType.CheckedOut` it returns nothing.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need `RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData`, this filter will behave differently if you specify properties, like `ItemIds`, but without setting any properties you will get all checked out items in the system (provided you have enough permissions.)

Comment: Any idea how to do the opposite? That is: enumerate items *not* checked out. (Need to manipulate items' history and now it throws: "Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager
.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: The item is checked-out."

Comment: Can you ask it in a separate question? It's difficult to understand what you need

Comment: Sort of resolved my own pain. Relevant condition is this: LockType.None != ((FullVersionInfo)versionedItem.VersionInfo).LockType