# How to get the list of all checked out item in tridion under all users accounts

Tags: 2013, core-service

I have a requirement where i need to find the list of all checked out item in Tridion under all Tridion users. I am using tridion 2013 SP1.

I can get all checked out items under my name by using below code.

```
 RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData filter = new RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData();
 XElement itemList = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
 Console.WriteLine("Count :: " + itemList.Descendants(tcm + "Item").Count());
```

How to get it for all users. Do i need to use some filter?

Comment: What rights does your current user have?

Comment: I have admin rights .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if the user (under which you are running the code) has proper rights your code should return the desired result for you, as I think the code is correct.

on the other side, if you want to list items checked out by specific user; you can use `RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData.LockUser` Property.

**UPDATE:**

I am little surprised that the code returning the items checked by one user only. 
But there is a alternate approach as well, though it may take much time to run the script but it should serve the puspose.

1. get all the users using `getSystemWideList`
2. Iterate through the user, and use your same code but set `RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData.LockUser` Property to the user.
3. collect the results from each iteration.

Comment: I need the list of checked out items for all users in my CMS. The code i pasted above gives the list of items checked out by me only.

Comment: Can you confirm that there are other items checked out by other users?

Comment: yes there are items checked out by other users.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, this solution worked for me . I will be generating this list once in a while so i am okay with retrieving the list of user first and iterating through it.

Answer (score 3):

There was a defect in 2013 (and SP1) that caused administrators to no longer see items checked out by other users. This has been addressed in a hotfix.

Until it is available for download on SDL Tridion World, I'd advice you to contact Customer Support and reference CM_2013.1.0.88013 (assuming you are on 2013 SP1).

Comment: This has since been made available on SDL Tridion World (as part of CM_2013.1.0.88066 - Cumulative hotfix): https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the similer question with answer in below link:

[How do I get a list of checked out items with the Core Service?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-checked-out-items-with-the-core-service)

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I am asking the list of all checked out items in Tridion not only mine.

Comment: That's what the other question deals with